# Selenium scraping of Instagram keeps showing "Something went wrong..." for unregistered account

Tags: web-scraping, instagram

I am building a webscraper for Instagram Accounts. It has been working well for 2 months but recently it kept experiencing "Something went wrong..." on the page. It used to work well even for unregistered account but i am not sure why it just suddenly stopped last week (HTML and xpath are changed as well). Going to instagram accounts still works on my browser but not in Selenium's webdriver browser though. it is only for instagram, other social media (other than Twitter) works.

I have not tried implementing anything but would like to obtain some suggestions on how to fix it so i can start implementing.

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely IP-Banned, try using proxies. I am pretty sure it will work after again.